# How to convert dataframe to json

Tags: python, json, list, pandas, list-comprehension

How can I convert dataframe into json structure?

```
df = 

name    size    imports
AAA     111     [222,333]
BBB     111     [333,444]
```

The result should be:

```
json = 
[
{"name":"AAA","size":111,"imports":["data.222","data.333"]},
{"name":"BBB","size":111,"imports":["data.33","data.444"]}
]
```

If I use this command `df.reset_index().to_json(orient='records')`, then I cannot customize values like `data.333` (i.e. add `data` and put the value into `".."`.

Comment: What is `type(df.imports.iloc[0])` ?

Comment: @jezrael: It's `[`.

Comment: I think `print (type(df.imports.iloc[0]))` and it is str or list I think.

Comment: @jezrael: It's `<type 'list'>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `apply` with `list comprehension` for add text `data.` to each value of `list`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name':['AAA','BBB'],
                   'sizeB':[111,111],
                   'imports':[[222,333],[333,444]]})

df.imports = df.imports.apply(lambda x: ['data.'+ str(y) for y in x])
print (df)
                imports name  sizeB
0  [data.222, data.333]  AAA    111
1  [data.333, data.444]  BBB    111

print (df.to_json(orient='records'))
[{"imports":["data.222","data.333"],"name":"AAA","sizeB":111},
 {"imports":["data.333","data.444"],"name":"BBB","sizeB":111}]
```

Comment: It gives me "imports":[data.222,data.333] without `".."`

Comment: I am a bit confused - `..` is not in desired output. I think I dont understand. Can you explain more?

Comment: I mean thta I need to get `"imports":["data.222","data.333"], but not "imports":[data.222,data.333]`. Sorry, if I haven't explained it well.